# Extracting the contents between two different strings using bash or perl

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have tried to scan through the other posts in stack overflow for this, but couldn't get my code work, hence I am posting a new question.

Below is the content of file `temp`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/<env:Body><dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management"><dp:timestamp>2015-01-
 22T13:38:04Z</dp:timestamp><dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i</dp:file><dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i</dp:file></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

This file contains the base64 encoded contents of two files names `test.txt` and `test1.txt`. I want to extract the base64 encoded content of each file to seperate files `test.txt` and `text1.txt` respectively.

To achieve this, I have to remove the xml tags  around the base64 contents. I am trying below commands to achieve this. However, it is not working as expected.

`sed -n '/test.txt"\>/,/\<\/dp:file\>/p' temp | perl -p -e 's@<dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">@@g'|perl -p -e 's@</dp:file>@@g' > test.txt`

`sed -n '/test1.txt"\>/,/\<\/dp:file\>/p' temp | perl -p -e 's@<dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">@@g'|perl -p -e 's@</dp:file></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope>@@g' > test1.txt`

Below command:

`sed -n '/test.txt"\>/,/\<\/dp:file\>/p' temp | perl -p -e 's@<dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">@@g'|perl -p -e 's@</dp:file>@@g'`

produces output:

```
 XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i

<dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i</dp:response>   </env:Body></env:Envelope>`
```

Howeveer, in the output I am expecting only first line `XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i`. Where I am commiting mistake?

When i run below command, I am getting expected output:

`sed -n '/test1.txt"\>/,/\<\/dp:file\>/p' temp | perl -p -e 's@<dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">@@g'|perl -p -e 's@</dp:file></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope>@@g'`

It produces below string

`lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i`

I can then easily route this to test1.txt file.

**UPDATE**

I have edited the question by updating the source file content. The source file doesn't contain any newline character. The current solution will not work in that case, I have tried it and failed. `wc -l temp` must output to `1`.

`OS: solaris 10`
`Shell: bash`

Comment: So you don't want this `lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i` as well ?

Comment: yes I dont want anything other than `XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i`

Comment: This should work then `awk 'match($0,/dp:file name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</,a){print a[1] > a[2]}' file`

Comment: I have updated my question to make my requirement more clearer

Comment: `awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

getting above error if I use your code.

Comment: It requires GNU awk, you would need to download it for the `match` to work, sorry :(

Comment: @user2607367 any time you get that specific error message it means you are using old, broken awk (usr/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used. Generally on Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead but as Jid mentions his suggestion requires gawk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/xpg4/bin/sed` works well here.

`/usr/bin/sed` is not working as expected in case if the file contains just 1 line.

below command works for a file containing only single line.

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/sed -n 's_<env:Envelope\(.*\)<dp:file name="temporary://BackUpDir/backupmanifest.xml">\([^>]*\)</dp:file>\(.*\)_\2_p' securebackup.xml 2>/dev/null
```

Without `2>/dev/null` this sed command outputs the warning `sed: Missing newline at end of file`.

This because of the below reason:

Solaris default sed ignores the last line not to break existing scripts because a line was required to be terminated by a new line in the original Unix implementation.

GNU sed has a more relaxed behavior and the POSIX implementation accept the fact but outputs a warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's_<dp:file name="\([^"]*\)">\([^<]*\).*_\1 -> \2_p' temp
```

- I add `\1 ->` to show link from file name to content but for content only, just remove this part
- posix version so on GNU sed use `--posix`
- assuming that base64 encoded contents is on the same line as the tag around (and not spread on several lines, that need some modification in this case)

Thanks to **JID** for full explaination below

---

**How it works**

```
sed -n
```

The -n means no printing so unless explicitly told to print, then there will be no output from sed

```
's_
```

This is to substitute the following regex using `_` to separate regex from the replacement.

```
<dp:file name=
```

Regular text

```
"\([^"]*\)"
```

The brackets are a capture group and must be escaped unless the `-r` option is used( `-r` is not available on posix). Everything inside the brackets is captured. `[^"]*` means 0 or more occurrences of any character that is not a quote. So really this just captures anything between the two quotes.

```
>\([^<]*\)<
```

Again uses the capture group this time to capture everything between the `>` and `<`

```
.*
```

Everything else on the line

```
_\1 -> \2
```

This is the replacement, so replace everything in the regex before with the first capture group then a `->` and then the second capture group.

```
_p
```

Means print the line

---

Resources

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: Could you please explain this code for me? what exactly this regex does?

Comment: I edited the answer to add explanations, hope you don't mind :) Also i changed `</dp:file>` to `.*` so that the rest of the line would be replaced as well :)

Comment: @JID i agree, very good initiative on both explaination and enhancement of the code

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But this command does only prints two lines. As per my question, I have to send base64 encoded strings to a file.

The bas64 string associated with `test.txt` must be sent to `test.txt` file and the one associated with `test1.txt` , must be sent to `test1.txt` file

Comment: Well, I have achieved this by tweaking commands a bit...I am using below to get the base64 content of 'test.txt' file:
`sed -n 's_<dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">\([^<]*\).*_\1_p' temp`

and below, for getting the base64 content of test1.txt

`sed -n 's_<dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">\([^<]*\).*_\1_p' temp`

Comment: I actually committed a mistake while posting this question. The file `temp` must not contain any newline and `wc -l temp` should give output `1`. I dont think this solution will work now, i tried it and it failed.

Comment: add maybe a `.*` before `<dp:file name` and retry